# phpstorm and new ubuntu/java update overheating

Tags: 16.04, java, openjdk, ide, intellij

3 days ago I updated Ubuntu and restarted.

My Java process, that launch phpstorm, go up to 600% CPU usage and kills my pc in about 20 second.

I was on phpstorm 8 with Java openJDK 8.

As test I tried to swap to the oracle version but same result!

Then I manually removed phpstorm from my system and updated it to the last version, the 10th.

Still overheating with no chance to work on it! any suggestion?

My system is:

> Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
>   Release:    16.04
>   Codename:   xenial
>
> uname -r  ----> 
>   4.4.0-45-generic
>
> cat /proc/cpuinfo
>   processor   : 0
>   vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
>   cpu family  : 6
>   model       : 42
>   model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
>   stepping    : 7
>   microcode   : 0x18
>   cpu MHz     : 832.421
>   cache size  : 6144 KB
>   physical id : 0
>   siblings    : 8
>   core id     : 0
>   cpu cores   : 4

```
     natty@natty-RC730:~$ cpupower frequency-info
    analyzing CPU 0:
      driver: intel_pstate
      CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
      CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
      maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
      hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.90 GHz
      available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
      current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 2.90 GHz.
                      The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                      within this range.

  current CPU frequency is 868 MHz.
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    25500 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
```

Edit from comments: I still get the following error:

```
 Oct 26 14:18:34 natty-RC730 kernel: [11779.535501] thermal thermal_zone0: critical temperature reached(98 C),shutting down Oct 26 14:18:35 natty-RC730 kernel: [11780.538680] thermal thermal_zone0: critical temperature reached(98 C),shutting down Oct 26 14:18:36 natty-RC730 kernel: [11781.549083] thermal thermal_zone0: critical temperature reached(98 C),shutting down
```

Comment: Please [edit] additional information into your post. What is the output of `cpupower frequency-info`

Comment: When did you last clean the dust out of your laptop?

Comment: Computer's aren't supposed to crash no matter how hard you hammer their CPU. This sounds like a hardware issue, i. e. a faulty or dusty cooling system.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be possible provide your system is well maintained. The  i7-2630QM CPU has [Thermal Monitoring Technologies.](http://ark.intel.com/products/52219/Intel-Core-i7-2630QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-2_90-GHz) this being the case, If the CPU is truly overheating (Max temp 100C) then the CPU must be faulty as it's designed to downclock and continue working if it gets hot.

Thermal Monitoring Technologies protect the processor package and the system from thermal failure through several thermal management features. An on-die Digital Thermal Sensor (DTS) detects the core's temperature, and the thermal management features reduce package power consumption and thereby temperature when required in order to remain within normal operating limits

**EDIT:**

Since you are using the intel_pstate driver and it doesn't appear to be working properly for you you could try disabling it and using acpi frequency control instead as described in [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544266/why-are-missing-the-frequency-options-on-cpufreq-utils-indicator/544273#544273) You could also install the indicator-cpufreq package and adjust clock rates manually. Note that changing to acpi frequency control will typically provide more choices for indicator-cpufreq than the intel-pstate driver.

If your system isn't well maintained, it could be packed with dust, the cooling fan may be failing or have failed. (None of us work well when we can't breathe.)  If this is the problem you'll find some options [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583155/prevent-nvidia-to-raise-performance-level-to-avoid-overheating/583987#583987)

Comment: but its happen! how can i solve this? cheers

Comment: You might find this post educational: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457597/cpu-turbo-boost-modify-temperature-limit-under-14-04

Comment: thanks a lot, even for editing my bad eng! ill read it carefully...but to me is java/update that start to make me mad!

Comment: is this one works even on 16.04? http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html

Comment: to me seems alls correct: `
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  ......

Comment: and got still: Oct 26 14:18:34 natty-RC730 kernel: [11779.535501] thermal thermal_zone0: critical temperature reached(98 C),shutting down
Oct 26 14:18:35 natty-RC730 kernel: [11780.538680] thermal thermal_zone0: critical temperature reached(98 C),shutting down
Oct 26 14:18:36 natty-RC730 kernel: [11781.549083] thermal thermal_zone0: critical temperature reached(98 C),shutting down

Comment: natty is out of support and reached EOL on October 28, 2012. I suggest that you upgrade to a supported version with a supported kernel: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: lol :D natty is my nickname of the laptop nothing to share with the old ubunut version...i was natty before and after the relase :D

Comment: Ok. Try my edited answer.

Comment: @ElderGeek: Might be a [hardware problem](http://askubuntu.com/a/583987/344926)

Comment: @Fabby Could be that the vents are packed with dust, cooling fan has failed, etc.

Comment: My idea exactly.

Comment: @ElderGeek  no the vents are ok... its java with phpstorm that burns my pc!

Comment: @ElderGeek ndicator-cpufreq package is installed from long time, but as described here with less feature than before http://askubuntu.com/questions/544266/why-are-missing-the-frequency-options-on-cpufreq-utils-indicator/544273#544273

Comment: Updated Answer.

Comment: later i will post some pics of the fan etc...looks so clean. the problem to me is a combination of last kernel+nvidia+java... last night for having a clean enviroment i formatted all...the result is that i cant login on graphics... i try at least 6 different nvidia driver... all start after kernel update!!!!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/842796/nvidia-last-kernel-update-and-login-loop-as-usual

Answer (score 0):

the things is not solved, but a fresh install of 16.04 with updated driver now not made the temperature so critical... there was no dust in the fan, the problem is still here related to how phpstorm use to "indexing" files and folder... java still runs on 600% and over!
thanks for all inputs!